# Models accessible only for authenticated user THAT CREATED THEM (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, repository, repository-pattern

I'm writing a software application to let the people have their own private archive of cooking recipes.

The *RecipeController* constructor contains:

```
$this->middleware('auth')
```

because only registered users can use recipes, but **I need to protect also the access to the models**.

The point is that **users can view and modify only their own recipes**.

Example: The user TortelliEngineer can create a recipe "Tortelli Secret Recipe" using the model *Recipe*; he can view, update and delete his recipe(s), but nobody else can see his precious "Tortelli Secret Recipe".

So, which is the cleanest way?

- I added a *user_id* attribute to the model **Recipe**.
- I must use this parameter every single time that I ask to the database for a **Recipe** (goodbye "findOrFail" by ID)
- That means that every time I make a request I must access the Request object that contains User that contains User_id
- using Auth::id() EVERY SINGLE TIME that I need one (or n) recipe

Like this:

```
class RecipeRepository{


public function all(){
    return Recipe::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->get();
}

public function find($recipe_id){
    return Recipe::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->where('id', $recipe_id)
                ->firstOrFail();
}
```

Is that correct? Do you hate me for this? Do you know better or more correct ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I make a method inside the model to check if someone is authorised, owner etc.. of something.

An example would be:

```
// User model

public function owns_recipe($recipe)
{

    return ($recipe->user_id == $this->id);

}
```

You can call this at the very beginning in of the methods of your controller:

```
// Controller

public function index (Request $request)
{

    $recipe = Recipe::find($request->id); // Get recipe

    $user = ... // Get user somehow

    if (!$recipe) App::abort(404); // Show 404 not found, or something

    if (!$user->owns_recipe($recipe)) App::abort(403); // Show 403 permission denied, or something


    ... // Do whatever you want :)

}
```

Comment: Nice and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways of approaching this, Laravel does provide some built-in methods for handling general authentication of actions.  In the first place I'd do something along the lines of what you intended (have a getRecipesByOwner method in RecipeRepository) and you can pass the user to it from the injected Request object:

```
// RecipeController

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $recipes = $this->recipeRepo->findRecipesByOwner($request->user());
}
```

In addition though, I'd recommend creating policies to manage whether or not a user is capable of updating/deleting/viewing individual recipes.  You can then authorize their actions in the controllers/blade templates/etc. via built-in methods like:

```
// Controller

public function update(Request $request, Recipe $recipe)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $recipe);
}

// Blade template

@can('update', $recipe)

@endcan
```

The documentation is available at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: On function index() I would prefer to manage the authorization inside the repository->findRecipes() function code, so I don't have to bother myself injecting Request in index() to use $request->user as parameter for the repository function.

Comment: Anyway your example is very similar to the intermediate tutorial of Laravel documentation, so you must be right

Comment: public function findRecipes(){
        return Auth::user()->recipes()->get();
    }